# Excecute cron in another server with php file

Tags: php, dns, cron

I have a website in hosting with a cronjob function and another domain in hosting without cron function.

Is it possible to call a file in the hosting without cron function using the cron function from server with this service?

Example:

I call a file `crondomain.php` with the cronjob from domain `www.1234.com`. The file `crondomain.php` with special code calls a file `cron.php` in the domain `www.5678.com`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to remove any comments that are not constructive to your question. Focus on your question and provide all relevant details and do not worry about including comments as the ones you had. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the remote script accessible via HTTP and you can use a file_get_contents or similar to make a HTTP request from the cron script which executes the remote script.

Example:
crondomain.php running with cron on www.1234.com:

```
<?Php
file_get_contents('http://www.5678.com/cron.php');
?>
```

Then you can do what you want in cron.php on www.5678.com.

Comment: I not are expert in php .. one example ?

Comment: Edited post with sample now.

Comment: I try it, but not work..
I make a file with your example in the domani 1234.com apply 777.. The cron.php in another server apply same 777.. I lunch in browser the crondomain.php (www.1234.com/crondomain.php.. But the cron.php has not been executed

Comment: Check if you can run cron.php by opening www.5678.com/cron.php in a browser.

Comment: if run cron.php work.. not try becouse i run it I can see if it works by other method until tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by creating one php file on server wherer cron job is available and in that php file run your code using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)  or [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).
pass arguments to that file with curl and exccute on that server.

Comment: I can not use this function .. I are noob.. You can give me an example?

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$Url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
       $data = curl_exec($ch);
       if (curl_errno($ch))
       {
  return curl_error($ch);
       }
       else {
          //process data
        }